# Php not working on other pages of my site

Tags: php, html

Guys I have an external php file and its code is

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['click'];
$query= "SELECT * FROM software where id='".$_SESSION['test']."' ";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);`
```

on my index page I have

```
<form method="POST">
<a href="exten.php"  name="click" type="submit" value="1">aaaa</a>
<input name="click" type="submit" value="2">
</form>
<?php print_r($row);?>
```

and it works completely fine. But on another page of my site called exten.php I    have

```
<?php print_r($row); ?>
```

which dosen't work if i direct user here onclick of link on second line of index

Comment: maybe just because of `session_start();` or `$con`

Comment: so.... start the session in the other file. That's what I think is going on here. `$row` is out of scope.

Comment: So how is it in scope of index.php file

Comment: *Hold on there cowboy* ........ `<a href="exten.php"  name="click" type="submit" value="1">aaaa</a>` - That should be an input here, not an `href`.

Comment: input also didn't work so i tried to change it to a link

Answer (score 0):

If your

```
<?php print_r($row);?>
```

is the only PHP code in your exten.php, it won't display anything because the $row variable that is set in your index page is not reachable.

If I get it well, you want to display the result of the click action on the button on a second page, named exten.php. If so, the action attribute on the form tag must be set.

```
<form action="exten.php" method="POST">
```

But if you want to display the value of what you have put in session (the variable *test*), the you have to start the session and then call your variable.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

That is true for any pages.

Not sure why you put the value of a form input into session and then put this session variable in your query but in any case, you should sanitize your input values before using them in a SQL query. For example:

```
$test = filter_var($_SESSION['test'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```